# ArcMap edit annotation tool button grey out?

Tags: arcmap, editing, annotation

ArcMap edit annotation tool button grey out?

I try to edit annotation, but can't because the select annotation button was grey out see image below
[image]

My annotation  was properly convert from label, store in Map.
[image]

Why I can't edit annotation? I was be able to edit annotation before, but I can't this time, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your annotation are stored in the map, the tool you try to use will work on an annotation class stored in a database (and of course only during an edit session).

To modify map annotation you need to use the black selection arrow (next right of the select tool on your screenpict). Just click on the annotation you want to modify and it should get selected (you'll see a dotted grey square around it). A right click let you access the annotation properties and the drawing toolbar will let you use some tool to modify it (like the rotation tool).

(In the layout view you need to first double click on the dataframe (the border will change to aching pattern) to be able to select annotation)

Comment: Great, that is what I thought. I solve my problem, see details in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I sovled my question.

You can **NOT** edit annotation, if the annotation is **stored in map** !!!

You can only edit annotation, if the annotation is stored in a **geodatabase**.

Here is step 1:  **create a new file geodatabase**

[image]

Step 2:
**export the shape file to geodatabase**

[image]

Step 3:  **select the new file geodatabase you just created as output value**
**type a new name in  feature classe field**
[image]

Step 4: **add the new feature class(in file geodatabase) to your map frame**
[image]

Step 5: **add label to feature class**
[image]
[image]

***Step 6:  Very important***

If you get error "**The coordinates or measures are out of bounds. Text**" later when you convert label to annotation, you might need to adjust the way how you label, I means, you should go back and forth on step 5, micro-adjust the properties on above screen to avoid downstream error.

Step 7: **convert label to annotation**

```
       You must first label the feature, check mark  number 1 in pic
       without this check mark, convert label to annotation is grey out.
```

[image]

Step 8: you could failed when convert, error is  "**The coordinates or measures are out of bounds. Text**"
the work around is adjust setting exactly like the picture shows you will fix the error!!!

[image]

Step 9:   when convertion completed successfully, a new annotation layer will be automatically add to your map frame.  Now you can start edit the annotation layer just like you edit other shape file. The edit annotion button now is no longer grey out, you can now resize, move the annotation label !!!!!

I click edit annotation button (blue circle in picture), then select a label, you can see that there is a highlighted rectangular box around the label, now you can resize and move it.

[image]

Step 10:  to change label text, you can open attribute table, change the field value, will get the text changed. see picture
[image]